# hibernate.connection.datasource property in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

In my application, I see a configuration in hibernate.cfg.xml file to connect to the database.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:autovendor</property>
```

and its been referenced as

```
InitialContext ct = null;
ct = new InitialConext();
ds = (DataSource)ct.lookup("java:autovendor")
```

what does the java:autovendor indicates here, Is it a java class??

Comment: "java:autovendor" is like a tag (it's just a string) that the application uses in order to lookup that connection from its internal registry. Typically this pattern is used in JNDI lookups (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface). It is basically the primary key for a hashmap of objects in the registry.

Comment: Where can I get the value for the key -> "java:autovendor"..If its in registry, where can I find it...

Comment: @user1050619, if the application is running on a server then check the list of jndi connections that are configured on that server for this application.

Comment: Are you running this code as a standalone jar, or are you running it on a server eg Tomcat, Weblogic, Glassfish etc?

Comment: Here is a good example of how to use this code with JNDI in Tomcat 6: http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-mysql-datasource-in-tomcat-6/

Comment: I understand jdbc/mkyongdb but how about this string -"java:comp/env/"...How does it get recognized??